# C header files with duplicates

Tags: c, header-files

I have 2 header files with overlaps as shown below:

**header1.h**

```
...
 __declspec(dllexport) void abc();
 __declspec(dllexport) void xyz();
...
```

**header2.h**

```
#define value1 1
#define value2 2
...
__stdcall void abc();
__stdcall void xyz();
...
```

**main.c**

```
#include "header1.h"
#include "header2.h"

main()
{
     somefunc(xxx, value1);
}
```

I am getting compile errors (inconsistent dll linkage). Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: What are the actual headers you're using? What are the actual symbols giving you problems? If they're your own code, either include one header in the other, or keep the declarations the same.

Comment: `__stdcall #define value1 1` ???

Comment: You give the compiler two `abc()` functions. One of them has `__declspec(dllexport)` , the other one doesn't. They must have the same signature.

Comment: the problem is that they have different signatures and that can't be edited. :(

Comment: I think there is no solution in that case. You can't have them in the same code.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible! We cannot have the same function name with different signatures and included as shown above. Thanks for your time everybody.

Answer (score 0):

In the C and C++ programming languages, an #include guard, sometimes called a macro guard, is a particular construct used to avoid the problem of double inclusion when dealing with the include directive

May be useful for you, there is concept header guards::

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard